# Store XML format data in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008, xquery

My query is:

```
Declare @xml1 xml='

<Root>
  <Dir Name="Test">
    <Dir Name="Test1">
      <File>File1<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File2<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File3<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File4<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File5<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File6<Size>375</Size></File>
    </Dir>
    <Dir Name="Test2" />
  </Dir>
</Root>'

Declare @t table (xmld xml)
Insert into @t values (@xml1)

select * from @t
```

I want to store the XML data in SQL Server table.

My expected output is:

```
FolderPath  FileName    FileSize    
--------------------------------
Test        -       -       
Test\Test1      File1       375     
Test\Test1      File2       375     
Test\Test1      File3       375     
Test\Test1      File4       375     
Test\Test1      File5       375
Test\Test2      -       -
```

I followed [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/) link for reference but not able to understand.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Shouldn't `FolderPath` be `Test\Test1` where you have files?

Comment: Oh yes you are right.I updated the output.

Comment: @RedDevil, are you sure about your XML namespaces? What is the reason to change them for each `<Dir>` tag?

Comment: @RedDevil, it seems that you are using namespaces as a directory name ?! 

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to apply. You _are_ storing `xml` data in a table. It appears that you are having trouble using a query to extract data from the `xml` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am proposing much better XML structure without namespaces use as a directory name. Even the `<File>` tag is no so kosher in the original XML.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml xml=
N'<Root>
    <Dir name="Test">
        <Dir name="Test1">
            <File name="File1" Size="375"/>
            <File name="File2" Size="375"/>
            <File name="File3" Size="375"/>
        </Dir>
        <Dir name="Test2">
            <File name="File1" Size="575"/>
            <File name="File2" Size="75"/>
            <File name="File3" Size="75"/>
        </Dir>
        <Dir name="Test3"/>
    </Dir>
</Root>';

SELECT dir.c.value('@name','VARCHAR(100)') + '\' +
     subdir.c.value('@name','VARCHAR(100)') AS folderPath
    , fil.c.value('@name','VARCHAR(100)') AS [fileName]
    , fil.c.value('@Size','VARCHAR(100)') AS [fileSize]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Dir') AS dir(c)
    CROSS APPLY dir.c.nodes('Dir') AS subdir(c)
    OUTER APPLY subdir.c.nodes('File') AS fil(c)
ORDER BY folderPath, [fileName];
```

> Output

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| folderPath | fileName | fileSize |
+------------+----------+----------+
| Test\Test1 | File1    | 375      |
| Test\Test1 | File2    | 375      |
| Test\Test1 | File3    | 375      |
| Test\Test2 | File1    | 575      |
| Test\Test2 | File2    | 75       |
| Test\Test2 | File3    | 75       |
| Test\Test3 | NULL     | NULL     |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Both the answers are absolutely wonderfurl!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @xml1 xml='
<Root>
  <Dir xmlns="Test">
    <Dir xmlns="Test1">
      <File>File1<Size>175</Size></File>
      <File>File2<Size>275</Size></File>
      <File>File3<Size>375</Size></File>
      <File>File4<Size>475</Size></File>
      <File>File5<Size>575</Size></File>
      <File>File6<Size>675</Size></File>
    </Dir>
    <Dir xmlns="Test2" />
  </Dir>
</Root>';


select 
    dr.d.value('namespace-uri(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as thedir,
    fl.f.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as thefile,    
    fl.f.value('*:Size[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as thesize 
from @xml1.nodes('//*:Dir') as dr(d)
outer apply dr.d.nodes('./*:File') as fl(f);


Declare @xml2 xml='
<Root>
  <Dir Name="Test">
    <Dir Name="Test1">
      <File>File1<Size>101375</Size></File>
      <File>File2<Size>102375</Size></File>
      <File>File3<Size>103375</Size></File>
      <File>File4<Size>104375</Size></File>
      <File>File5<Size>105375</Size></File>
      <File>File6<Size>106375</Size></File>
    </Dir>
    <Dir Name="Test2" />
  </Dir>
</Root>';


select  
    dr.d.value('@Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as thedir,
    fl.f.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as thefile,    
    fl.f.value('*:Size[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as thesize 
from @xml2.nodes('//Dir') as dr(d)
outer apply dr.d.nodes('./File') as fl(f);
```